# How to organise reindexation of full-text-search database with kafka sink?

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-kafka

Imagine that you have text search db (lets say elastic) and you fill it with data by listening to several kafka topics + making http api call to fetch some extra data.
(This is service A)

At some point you will need to add extra field to the index and thus make full reindexation to populate it.

How to achieve this efficiently? What if topics that you are listening to have delete policy and doesn’t have all historical data?

So far I’ve come up with several solutions and neither looks good enough:

- go to rest api of the service that produces data for topic (service B) and ask for that data. This can be very slow and will hurt downstream service’s api backend
- Ask service B to offload all of the data into separate kafka topic. This might work, but now service B adjusts to service A (more coupling) by providing this trigger. And also this operation looks kinda dangerous.

Even without delete policy there can be a situation when new data from service B is not in old log records, and we need it in service A.

What do people usually do in practice?

Answer (score 0):

This is subjective, here is one approach to do it

Have an additional Kafka sink, this would dump data into a object store with compression (blob,s3,minio...) of some kind. When you need a replay, you use this object store as the source and then pass in data to either the kafka topic or have transformation that directly process it and dump data into ES itself. This is a classic back-fill pipeline where data is replayed from cold stores (lesser cost of storage and an on-demand compute that dumps the data and gets spun down)

On the ES side itself, you can create a new index and populate the data. Then point the alias to the new index and drop the old index if it is no longer needed.